# Is there a cross platform barcode scanner application with an SDK available for mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, barcode-scanner

I would like to create a barcode scanning applciation for iPhone and Android. I have found for iPhone "Red Laser" http://www.redlaser.com/SDK.aspx.

I would like to know of any software people know about that has a shared license for both Android and iPhone devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Zebra Crossing (ZXing)](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has an Android barcode scanning library with an iPhone port that was "contributed and/or intermittently maintained".

Comment: The iPhone port is a complete rewrite; I wouldn't really call it "cross platform" as much as a separate package. It might get better if they rewrite the Android source to use the C++ version through JNI, but I don't see that happening. Last I checked, the C++ version didn't support 1D barcodes.

Answer (score 2):

[ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net), GNU LGPL 2.1.

Support iOS 4's AVCaptureInput (capture barcode from video camera), and Java too.